# disable scroll body when menu is open wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, menu, onclick

My menu in wordpress has the following code:

```
<nav role='navigation'>
    <div id="menuToggle" onclick="lockScroll()" >
        <input type="checkbox"  />
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <ul id="menu">
            <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
            ) );
        ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And this jQuery function to disable scroll in body when `#menuToggle` is clicked:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function(lockScroll) {
        if ($('body').hasClass('lock-scroll')) {
            $('body').removeClass('lock-scroll');
        }
        else {
            $('body').addClass('lock-scroll');
        }
  });
</script>
```

But it always gives me the error

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function   at
>   HTMLDocument.

Comment: try this script. `<script>
 jQuery(function(lockScroll) {
        if (jQuery('body').hasClass('lock-scroll')) {
            jQuery('body').removeClass('lock-scroll');
        }
        else {
            jQuery('body').addClass('lock-scroll');
        }
  });
  </script>`

Comment: Replace `$` to `jQuery`

Comment: Easiest way to remove the error: `(function ($, root, undefined) { // YOUR CODE HERE \\ })(jQuery, this);` - this should be your "ready" function and your code should be inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not exactly sure what 'open' means in your case. This code should most likely do the right thing or push you in the right direction:

```
jQuery( '#menuToggle' ).click( function() {

    jQuery( 'body' ).addClass( 'lock-scroll' );

} );

jQuery( document ).on( 'mousedown', function( e ) {

    var c = jQuery('#menuToggle');

    if( !c.is( e.target ) && c.has( e.target ).length === 0 ) {

        jQuery( 'body' ).removeClass( 'lock-scroll' );

    }


} );
```

If you click `#menuToggle` the `lock-scroll` class is added (first part). As soon as you click outside of `#menuToggle` it will be removed (second part).

Comment: this only works the first time i click. It whont remove lock-scroll class

Comment: @LuisGil: Yeah I use that for mobile menus mainly ... in my case the trigger button is not visible when the menu is open. You haven't posted an example so i could just guess :P

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This:-

```
jQuery(function(lockScroll) {
        if (jQuery('body').hasClass('lock-scroll')) {
            jQuery('body').removeClass('lock-scroll');
        }
        else {
            jQuery('body').addClass('lock-scroll');
        }
  });
```

Comment: That enables always the scroll. I think mi script is not correct to disable the scroll when cckick the button and if close menu activate scroll.

Comment: Whith your code it gives me an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: lock is not defined. And scroll is always disable.

Answer (score 0):

This way a can disable the scroll when click

```
<script>
    jQuery('#menuToggle').click( function(){

    jQuery( 'body' ).addClass( 'lock-scroll' );
        });

    </script>
```

How can i remove class when click again?